# Setting directories in vimrc

Tags: vim, phpunit

I'm using a plugin for vim, c9/phpunit, for PHPUnit testing, it requires a path to my src, tests, and phpunit directories defined in my vimrc.

At the moment, I use vim-rooter to set my cwd to the root of my repo.

Is there a way to tell c9/phpunit to go to < current-working-directory >/module/Search/src, < current-working-directory >/module/Search/tests, and < current-working-directory >/vendor/phpunit from inside the vimrc so that it automatically gets the required paths when I open a file?

Comment: I have no idea what `c9/phpunit` is, but perhaps Tim Pope's plugin [projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) might help you.

Comment: What does the documentation of that plugin say about that subject?

Answer (score 0):

I  have created a function for your need.

```
  :function! GetCwd()
  :let path = expand('%:p:h')
  :let mod1 = path.'/module/Search/tests'
  :let mod2 = path.'/module/Search/src'
  :set path+=mod1
  :set path+=mod2
  :endfunc
```

You can put this in .vimrc file.
Add an auto command like

```
   :au BufEnter *.* :call GetCwd()
```

This will add those subdirectories into path.

(This is an example function. Depending upon your need, you can use variables from plugins, or some other paths)
Your plugin itself has several variables like g:phpunit_testroot. You can use relevant variable I. The above function.